# InvalidAuthenticityToken between subdomains when logging in with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just added SSL on secure.mydomain.com. When someone logs in, they POST from a form on the main (www) subdomain to the secure subdomain. That's causing an InvalidAuthenticityToken error to be generated.

I've read that it's necessary to share session data across subdomains. To do this, I've already added:

```
config.action_controller.session = { :domain => '.mydomain.com' }
```

to config/environments/production.rb. This, unfortunately, has not fixed the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3, if that's what you're using, wants you to make this change in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key => '[my key]',
  :domain => '.example.com'
}
```

Give that a go. If things still don't work as expected, inspect the cookie in the browser to see if it has any special domain setting at all. That'll help narrow down whether it's the setting or the getting that's the issue :/

Comment: For different domains for different environments, like `lvh.me` for `development`, you can use something like the following: `domain: {
  production: '.example.com',
  development: '.example.dev'
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)`

Answer (score 0):

How recently did you make this change? Your browser could still have the old cookies, which would need to be deleted before you'd notice a change in behavior.

Just throwin' it out there :)

Comment: Am I setting the domain option correctly? Heroku, but not webrick, tells me it's deprecated.

Comment: @Michael: what version of Rails is this?

Comment: @Michael: see new answer, then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is missing in your application layout

`<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

Answer (score 0):

I have a front-end and a rails back-end api in different subdomains, the code bellow works for me:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: :same_origin?
  before_action :verify_authenticity_token, unless: :same_origin

  private

  def same_origin?
    request.host == Rails.application.config.hosts.first
  end
end
```