# Invalid Authenticity Token When Logging Out with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My users can login at myapp.com and it will redirect them to their subdomain, e.g. username.myapp.com

This works because I have

```
Downhill::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_domain_session', :domain => :all
```

in `session_store.rb` & a  method in my application controller that checks the subdomain against username (so you can't login to other users' subdomains).

For testing purposes, `username.myapp.com` and myapp.com both show a user's data after logging in.

The problem: when the user logs out from `username.myapp.com`, they get

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy
```

BUT: when they instead logout from `myapp.com` it logs out just fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT

I've overridden both `after_sign_out_path_for` and `after_sign_in_path_for`

```
 def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
   root_url
 end

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   dashboard_url(:subdomain => current_user.subdomain)
 end
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I think this line is missing in your application layout

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: No it's definitely there. Again, it works if I log out from the root domain.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way to do this is to explicitly set the session domain as discussed here: [InvalidAuthenticityToken between subdomains when logging in with Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456208/invalidauthenticitytoken-between-subdomains-when-logging-in-with-rails-app). Devise also has problems with IE and subdomains - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains.

My solution:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  key: '_app_session',
  domain: Rails.configuration.domain
}

# config/environments/development.rb
config.domain = 'lvh.me'

# config/environments/production.rb
config.domain = 'my_app.com'
```

If you check cookies in a browser, you will see cookies for domains 'my_app.com' and '.my_app.com' in production environment.

Comment: You can also do something like `domain: {
  production: '.example.com',
  development: '.example.dev'
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)` as shown here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-subdomains